# Data missing when excel export from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

During exporting excel from gridview the data of a column known as Account Number prefixes 0 are removed. Please guide me for the same

Comment: Refer this, [How to ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), So anyone can understand and help you in a Proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get Account number into a string variable so as to protect leading zero, then while exporting to excel, you need to set cell type to string before you set the value to cell.